# Next Js - How to retrieve data from the api requiring authorization (via axios)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, authorization, server-side-rendering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT8Pn.png)

***user = Cookies.get("user")***

I can't get access to this road. I used cookies to store user data including the token.
Please I need Help

Comment: Please use code snippets, do not use images for code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your using Strapi CMS and request method for authenticated roots must be POST not GET here the example :

```
const {data ,status} = await 
   axios.post('https://localhost:1337/posts',{
       headers : { 
           Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
   });
 if(status === 200){
   setData(data)
  }else{
   console.log('eeror')
   }
```

make sure to mark the find method from strapi admin otherwise you will get 403 error in strapi user has jwt not token so make sure the token is the jwt which come from strpai when user login!

Comment: I had a 401 Server Error

Comment: while login in body pass identifier instrad of email like :                       
const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/auth/local', {
  identifier: 'reader@strapi.io',
  password: 'strapi',
});